# Check if a value is equal to the modulo of another number in a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to get an equivalent of this in Django

`if idx % 3 == 2:` do something

idx is an index in a forloop but I have simplified the code

I used this:

```
{% ifequal idx|divisibleby:3 2 %}
    do something
{% endifequal %}
```

It seems like the `divisibleby` filter returns `True` so it is almost impossible to compare the number 2 after getting its modulo.

Comment: Creating your own custom filter which will return division result may be a helpful solution for you. here is a tutorial http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DivisibleBy](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L795) just does a modulo to check whether or not the final value is equal to 0, there isn't anything stopping you making your own template tag using the exact same code without the final check

```
@register.filter(is_safe=False)
def modulo(value, arg):
    return int(value) % int(arg)


{% ifequal idx|modulo:3 2 %}
```

Comment: I tried using your sample but there is an `invalid filter error` thrown

Comment: @Tushortz - You need to define it as a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) before you can use it

Answer (score 2):

`idx % 3 == 2` exactly if `(idx - 2) % 3 == 0`

Thus

```
{% if idx | add:-2 | divisibleby:3 %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

should do what you want, I think.

Comment: `divisibleby` returns a `boolean`. I don't think it would work

Comment: Yes, `divisibleby` returns a boolean. That's why I used `{% if %}` rather than `{% ifequal %}`. Haven't tested my approach yet, though.

Comment: oh I get your logic now.I'll test it. It seems right though @das-g

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, `divisbleby` will only return `True` or `False` so besides building your own template tag like @sayse suggested you could also provide a set of numbers `x` where `x % 3 ==2` and then just compare in your template like this:

In your views `context['correct_numbers'] = { x for x in range(100) if x%3 ==2}`

Then in your template:

```
{% if idx in correct_numbers %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```